# C# OpenFileDialog opening twice

Tags: c#

I am having a problem with a windows form coded in Visual Studio using C# as part of a web development course. When I click on the menu item ('Import') the file dialogue box opens twice.

The first dialogue seems incorrect as it does not have the filter or title applied. Then the second dialogue box which immediately opens afterward has the correct filter and title applied.

Obviously it is only meant to open once to enable me to read the selected file and add it to the Listbox. This works, but only once I have selected the file twice.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
private void importToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text|*.txt";
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Choose a file to import";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Oh. No file selected!");
        }

        else
        {
            string usersFile = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(usersFile);

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                groceryList.Items.Add(line);
            }
        }
```

Comment: The first `ShowDialog` is unncessary

Comment: Yeah it is frustrating for me too but I believe it is to get the basics of C#. Not really what I expected. Thanks all for your help. I guess it's a stupid mistake, but what do you expect from an absolute beginner!

Comment: I assume @Gemack asked this because it is part of the Microsoft doc [How to: Open Files Using the OpenFileDialog Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-open-files-using-the-openfiledialog-component). The example they put there behave as he described. If you're just starting to learn some behaviours are not so obvious, and a bit more support for newbies would be welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Start of your code you have

```
private void importToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

this is unneccessary, the ShowDialog will show a dialog with the filters not correctly set up as your next lines have:

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text|*.txt";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Choose a file to import";
```

Then you ShowDialog again.

Therefore, just remove the first

```
 openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, now it seems obvious that the filters wouldn't have been applied when I called the dialogue box first. Hopefully eventually I get used to the 'flow' of it!

Comment: no problem, sometimes doing what CodeCaster suggested in his comment is the best way to see how your code "flows"